# History of the CERT secure coding standards?

Tags: secure-coding, standards

My question is when and why did researchers decide to create the CERT secure coding standards?

Is there anything about the history of this standards? I can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be too snarky, but did you try googling "cert secure coding history"? First hit:
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/History

I believe the first paragraph covers "when and why":

> The idea of a CERT secure coding standard arose at the Spring 2006 meeting of the C Standards Committee in Berlin, Germany. The C Standard is an authoritative document, but ... its language is obscure and often impenetrable. A secure coding standard would be targeted primarily toward C language programmers and would provide actionable guidance on how to code securely in the language.